# Assume f() is defined. In the statement a = f(), a is always a function.

Tags: python, function

Assume f() is defined. In the statement a = f(), a is always a function.

Why it is wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this. Could you please provide what errors you are seeing? A more practical example, as well?

Comment: `a` will be the return type from your function as you are calling the function.

Comment: What do do you mean "wrong"? We can't tell you if it is wrong or not because we don't know what `f()` returns. I recommend providing an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show a concrete example of what is meant.

Comment: True or False for this question, and its answer is false.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `a = f()`  `a` become what the function `f` returns. It can be anything, even a function too as long as `f()` returns a function.

If you do `a = f`  and `f` is a function already defined , then `a` always be a function as long as you don't re-define `a`.